# Can OpenRewrite work with Ant/Ivy-based projects?

Tags: ant, ivy, openrewrite

There are instructions for Gradle and Maven, but would this work with projects based on Ant and Ivy?  If so, how?  If not, is that something on the roadmap?

Answer (score 0):

Requests to run recipes against ANT projects come up from time to time; While this isn't officially supported we do have an issue to track documentation around such an implementation: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-docs/issues/247

Also: I had missed your question earlier since it was not tagged with OpenRewrite; apologies for the wait!